# Firebase hosting generates 404 only in America

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-monitoring

I have an API hosted on Google Firebase : Functions + Hosting (for cache). The URL is https://api.carbonfight.app.
Firebase hosting has nothing difficult in its configuration, only one rewrite to a Firebase function.

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/v1/**",
        "function": "v1",
        "region": "europe-west6"
      }
    ],
    "redirects": [ {
      "source": "/",
      "destination": "/v1/documentation",
      "type": 301
    } ]
  }
```

The problem is, this API does not work in South and North America, and I have no idea why. Here is Google monitoring uptime check.

[Google Monitoring screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyVMp.png)

In Google Logs, I only see that website returns a 404, with no other information.
I tried to deploy again and again, but nothing changes. Regions with problems are always the same and never works. It's a new API, and it never worked before in these regions. The other regions works perfectly.

Any idea about what happen and how to resolve it ?

Comment: I just had to wait 3 days... now everything works. Seems like Hosting need a delay before beeing ok everywhere.